# SQL Server Stored Procedure get nearest available date to parameter

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, compare

I have a table of database size information. The data is collected daily. However, some days are missed due to various reasons.  Additionally we have databases which come and go over or the size does not get recorded for several databases for a day or two. This all leads to very inconsistent data collection regarding dates. I want to construct a SQL procedure which will generate a percentage of change between any two dates (1 week, monthly, quarterly, etc.) for ALL databases The problem is what to do if a chosen date is missing (no rows for that date or no row for one or more databases for that date). What I want to be able to do is get the nearest available date for each database for the two dates (begin and end).

For instance, if database Mydb has these recording dates:

```
2015-05-03
2015-05-04
2015-05-05
2015-05-08
2015-05-09
2015-05-10
2015-05-11
2015-05-12
2015-05-14
```

and I want to compare 2015-05-06 with 2015-05-14

The 2015-05-07 date is missing so I would want to use the next available date which is 2015-05-08. Keep in mind, MyOtherDB may only be missing the 2015-05-06 date but have available the 2015-05-07 date. So, for MyOtherDb I would be using 2015-05-07 for my comparison.

Is there a way to proceduralize this with SQL WITHOUT using a CURSOR?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too much into this, simple do a "BETWEEN" function in your where clause that takes the two parameters.

In your example, if you perform the query:

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE_AUDIT WHERE DATE BETWEEN param1 /*2015-05-06*/ and param2 /*2015-05-14*/
```

It will give you the desired results.

```
select (b.dbsize - a.dbsize ) / a.dbsize *100 dbSizecChangePercent from
( select top 1 * from dbAudit where auditDate = (select min(auditDate) from dbAudit where auditDate between '01/01/2015' and '01/07/2015')) a
cross join 
(select top 1 * from dbAudit where auditDate = (select max(auditDate) from dbAudit where auditDate between '01/01/2015' and '01/07/2015')) b
```

The top 1 can be replaced by a group by. This was assuming only 1 db aduit per day

Comment: Maybe. What if the nearest endpoint to the beginning is before the start of the interval?

Comment: I am not looking to return all the rows between. I only want the endpoints so as to compute the size difference and return a percentage of change.